# How can I display a nested value in a state array object in React?

Tags: reactjs, state, textfield, nested-object

I am a beginner to React. I'm trying to display `"LicType"` property of the state object that is depicted in the picture below as a value for textfield.

Now had searchJson been `searchJson:"random text here"`

I would use `<TextField 
              value={values.searchJson}/>` had searchJson not been nested like that.

[image: React state screenshot]

How do I display or access `LicType`,`nextOfKin`, or `accountNotes` as a value for a textfield?

Note: `values` passed through props.

### Edit

Values.searchJson[0].LicType generates the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined
```

Comment: use ```searchJson[0].LicType```

Comment: i've tried this byt still get an error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined
EditStudentAccount.render
src/components/mainFlow/editStudentAccount/EditStudentInfo.js:97
   94 | autoComplete="fname"
   95 | margin="normal"
   96 | variant="outlined" style={{width:'100%'}}
>  97 | value={values.searchJson[0].fname}
      | ^   98 | /></Grid>
   99 | 
  100 |

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @JuniusL. I found a workaround given the urgency. I ended up assigning the json response to the state with the index only instead of the whole array object. 
 ``` .then(response=>{this.setState({searchJson:response.data[0]})})``` instead of   ```.then(response=>{this.setState({searchJson:response.data})})```

Answer (score 2):

searchJson is Array, so you access by index: values.searchJson[0].LicType

Comment: I've tried this but i still get an error. 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined
EditStudentAccount.render
src/components/mainFlow/editStudentAccount/EditStudentInfo.js:97
   94 | autoComplete="fname"
   95 | margin="normal"
   96 | variant="outlined" style={{width:'100%'}}
>  97 | value={values.searchJson[0].fname}
      | ^   98 | /></Grid>
   99 | 
  100 |

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it did help a bit to figure out a workaround
I ended up assigning the json response to the state with the index only instead of the whole array object. 
 ``` .then(response=>{this.setState({searchJson:response.data[0]})})``` instead of   ```.then(response=>{this.setState({searchJson:response.data})})```

Answer (score 1):

Your array has no values in it, hence the first item is undefined. You need to perform a null check first:

```
const val = searchJson.length && searchJson[0].LicType
```

Or:

```
const val = searchJson.length ? searchJson[0].LicType : ""
```

The same goes for when you're accessing `values.searchJson[0].fname` which is the error you are encountering.

Comment: but when I'm viewing the state via dev tools of the browser, it clearly shows the value assigned, as per the pic attached in the question....

Comment: The error happens in your EditStudentInfo.js file and is related to trying to access the property `fname` on an undefined object. Can you post that part of your code up here?

Comment: I found a workaround given the urgency. I ended up assigning the json response to the state with the index only instead of the whole array object. 
 ``` .then(response=>{this.setState({searchJson:response.data[0]})})``` instead of   ```.then(response=>{this.setState({searchJson:response.data})})```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround given the urgency. I ended up assigning the json response to the state with the index only instead of the whole array object. 
 `.then(response=>{this.setState({searchJson:response.data[0]})})` instead of   `.then(response=>{this.setState({searchJson:response.data})})`